# message inbox mysql group by sender or recipient

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a message table

`message_id`, `sender_id`, `recipient_id`, `subject`, `message`, `read`, `sender_deleted`,`recipient_deleted`, `updated_at`, `created_at`

I'd like to create and inbox like android, so I need to just display the latest message grouped by `recipient_id` OR `sender_id` (i.e. if the last message was sent by me it needs to group by the recipient and display their details), not group every message sent by me to any user.

I'm using `Laravel` and have come up with the following:

```
$messages = DB::table('cf_messages')
            ->select(DB::raw('*, max(message_id) as message_id'))
                ->where('sender_id', '=', $user->id)        
                ->where('sender_deleted', '=', false)   
                    ->orWhere('recipient_id', '=', $user->id)
                    ->where('recipient_deleted', '=', false)                
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('if (sender_id = '.$user->id.', recipient_id, sender_id)'))       
            ->orderBy('message_id', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

This appears to be obtaining and grouping the rows correctly, but can I have someone confirm this?

This issue I have is although the `message_id` is coming up correct if I dump the result I get the incorrect subject, message, etc... It's like I have to do a query again given the correct `message_id` to get the appropriate row of data? How can the message id be correct but other data showing in-correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is typical SQL behaviour based on your `group by` conditions.

Since you are squashing together multiple rows of information, SQL returns random information in other columns which are not grouped by or doesn't have any aggregates on them.

Your solution would be to inner join on same table to receive the correct message information, as such:

```
$messages = DB::table('cf_messages')
        ->select(DB::raw('cf_messages.sender_id,cf_messages.recipient_id, cfm.subject, cfm.message, cfm.read, max(cf_messages.message_id) as message_id'))
        ->join('cf_messages as cfm','max_message_id','=','cfm.message_id')
        ->where('cf_messages.sender_id', '=', $user->id)        
        ->where('cf_messages.sender_deleted', '=', false)   
        ->orWhere('cf_messages.recipient_id', '=', $user->id)
        ->where('cf_messages.recipient_deleted', '=', false)                
        ->groupBy(DB::raw('if (cf_messages.sender_id = '.$user->id.', cf_messages.recipient_id, cf_messages.sender_id)'))
        ->orderBy('max_message_id', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Okay, I think I see where you are heading. I get violation error - renamed all variables in where statement like sender_id to cf_messages.sender_id BUT it still appears not to be returning the correct subject/message corresponding to the message_id .. Any ideas? Is it common practice to just do another query for each correct message_id or should it really be all in one - if so above doesn't appear to be working correctly, hope you can provide further advice :)

Comment: It should return the correct message_id. Unless message_id is not unique.
Yes it is common practice, due to how SQL handles aggregate results.

Comment: message_id is the PK - it's still returning the subject, message, etc. as though it's just the first one it comes to. message_id is correct (the latest). So I've added (note change of $messages query to now named $inbox so I can use messages in my foreach loop) ... 

foreach ($inbox as $v) {
         $messages[] = Message::where('message_id', '=', $v->message_id)->firstOrFail();
  }

For it to work, but it would be nice to get your example to work, just unsure why it's not working...

Comment: Fixed it. The joins were being done on a random `message_id` instead of the aggregate `message_id`. I changed the alias to `max_message_id` to avoid ambiguity.